# How to change Password_Digest and add addresing in JMeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, password-encryption

I have to add wss and addresing wsa to my SOAP Request. I have tried doing that using SOAP Message UsernameToken but it failed

> Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + Base64 ( SHA-1 ( password ) ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use [WS-Security Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity) which provides a custom [PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) called **SOAP Message UsernameToken** where you can specify the [UsernameToken](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm) details:

[image]

More information: [Running SOAP WS-Security Load Tests in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-soap-ws-security-load-tests-in-jmeter)

Comment: As I said, I used SOAP Message UsernameToken component, but it failed